# Linux Kernel lock_sock Function

Tags: c, tcp, linux-kernel

What is the purpose of using the function `lock_sock(struct sock *sk)` in the kernel space? And how does it effect the corresponding socket in the user space, and will the OS be able to send packets after locking the sock?

Answer (score 4):

That's just a locking function, to prevent simultaneous access to the socket data structures from two differen threads. It doesn't have any effect outside the kernel. The "unlock" function is called `release_sock()`.